# 'CloudKit/CKDefines.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

At the moment i play a little bit with CloutKit and test this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/83116/beginning-cloudkit-tutorial

During compiling I get the following error for the simulator:

```
#import "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/Headers/CloudKit.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/Headers/CloudKit.h:10:9: error: 'CloudKit/CKDefines.h' file not found
#import <CloudKit/CKDefines.h>
        ^
/Users/steve/Downloads/BabiFud-Starter/BabiFud/Establishment.swift:26:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CloudKit'
import CloudKit
```

The funny thing is the file CKDefines existes and the code compile for iOS device.

Any idea what the issue could be?

PS: I use Xcode 6.3.1 (6D1002), iCloud capability is enabled for the app, i cleanedy alread several times :) ....

Comment: I have the problem on Xcode 7.0 beta (7A120f) too

Answer (score 0):

That error sounds like it's missing the CKDefines.h file. If you have another Xcode, can you try to add your CKDefines.h from your old Xcode:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/Headers/CKDefines.h
```

and copy it to the Xcode-beta one:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/Headers/
```

Or in one command (assuming in /Applications/ and Xcode.app + Xcode-beta.app:

```
cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/Headers/CKDefines.h /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/Headers/
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question, the file is not missing this is not the problem. This was the first thing i checked.